# Reading registry in windows service

Tags: c#, visual-studio, windows-services

I have made a windows service using VS2017 template and it have created two classes: Program.cs and Service1.cs:

Program.cs Main() function code is separated as below:

```
#if DEBUG
    Service1 service = new Service1();
    service.OnDebug();
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(System.Threading.Timeout.Infinite);

#else
    ServiceBase[] ServicesToRun;
    ServicesToRun = new ServiceBase[]
    {
        new Service1()
    };
    ServiceBase.Run(ServicesToRun);

#endif
```

It helps me while I debug my service before release.

In Service1.cs class I have OnDebug() method:

```
public void OnDebug()
{
    OnStart(null);
}
```

and OnStartMethod() looks like this:

```
protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
{
    const string keyPath = "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\\Software\\MyKey";
    string companyCardNumber = null;

    while (companyCardNumber == null || companyCardNumber.Equals(""))
    {
        companyCardNumber = (string)Registry.GetValue(keyPath, "CompanyCardNumber", null);

        if (companyCardNumber != null && !companyCardNumber.Equals(""))
        {
            break;
        }
        Debug.WriteLine("company card number in registry is empty or key doesn't exist");
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000);
    }
    //more code...
}
```

Now the problem is that when i use DEBUG mode in VS it goes to `//more code` and program correctly read value from the registy. But when I switch to RELEASE mode and deploy service and then install, it loops in this `while` and after

`companyCardNumber = (string)Registry.GetValue(keyPath, "CompanyCardNumber", null);`

`companyCardNumer` doesn't have any value.

What causes this problem? Do I need any administrative privileges to read values from the registry? It would be weird, because as user I can modify registy. Another thing I noticed is state of service, because most services are launched, but mine is launching (if i can say that). But it's still working but `companyCardNumber` is empty.

Comment: Under which User does your Service run?

Comment: HKEY_*CURRENT_USER* is specific to the user the service is running under, i.e. LocalService by default - not your account.

Comment: I'm using LocalService as Account property in my installer. Should it be: User?

Comment: What if there is more than one logged on user?  The correct approach depends on what specifically you are trying to achieve.

Comment: using HKEY_CURRENT_USER was a mistake. Instead I should use HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE. Now with User: LocalService everything is working. Thanks :)